# In a NOR gate not connected to any power supply, how can the output be '1' if both of the inputs are '0'?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, logic-level

I was reading about SR Latches and this very weird (and silly) question popped up in my head.

[image]

Here, when A and B is 0, then Q is 1.

Suppose that this NOR gate is lying in air, not connected to any power supply. Then as there is no potential or current passing through A or B, we can say that the inputs are 0 and 0. Then according to the truth table, Q must be 1! How is that even possible? What does it even mean?

Comment: *Then as there is no potential or current passing through A or B, we can say that the inputs are 0 and 0* - No, we can't. In addition to the answer below. Floating inputs are taking a value that depend on their internal implementation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for hypothesis.

Comment: @TonyM What's wrong with hypothetical questions? :)

Comment: Read the last paragraph of this one and you'll see... :-)  (no offence, OP)

Comment: For people who have the same question but are not quite satisfied by the answer given, see this video: https://youtu.be/KM0DdEaY5sY?t=300  . Here, just before connecting, the O/P was 0 (which should have been 1) but as soon as he powers the thing up, even though no current flows as I/P, the O/P is 1 (as expected)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The truth table is only true when there is power to the device.

Without power, a NOR gate is a NON-gate, or NOT-A-gate.